# Matching problem in a recursive way

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recursion, derangements

> Suppose there are $n$ people invited to a party. Seats are assigned and a name card is made for each guest. However, floral arrangements on the table unexpectedly obscure the name cards. When the $n$ guests arrive, they seat themselves randomly.
>
> Show that the probability that no one seats at the assigned seats is $$P_n = \frac{n-1}{n} P_{n-1} + \frac1n P_{n-2}.$$

My work:

> We consider a letter $i$, where $i \in {1, \dots, n}$.
>
> Let $E$ denote the event that no one sits at the right spot.
>
> Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable s.t. $X_i = 1$ indicates the ith person sits at the right spot.
>
> Then $Pr(E) = Pr(E \cap X_i = 0) + Pr(E \cap X_i = 1)$.
>
> Note that $Pr(E \cap X_i = 1) = 0$ because it's impossible.
>
> Then only need to compute:
> \begin{align}
> Pr(E \cap X_i = 0) 
> &= \sum_{k = 1, k \neq i}^{n}Pr(E \cap \text{person i in seat j}) \\ 
> &= \sum_{k = 1, k \neq i}^{n} 
> \left( Pr(E \vert S_{i,j} \cap S_{j,i}) \times Pr(S_{i,j}\cap S_{j,i}) \\ 
> + Pr(E \vert S_{i,j} \cap S_{j,i}^C) \times Pr(S_{i,j}\cap S_{j,i}^C) 
> \right)
> \end{align}
> where $S_{i,j}=\{\text{person }i\text{ in seat }j\}$ and $S_{i,j}^C$ denotes the complement, $S_{i,j}^C=\{\text{person }i\text{ not in seat }j\}$.
>
> Then
> $$Pr(E \vert \text{person i in seat j} \cap \text{person j in seat i}) = P_{n-2},$$
> $$Pr(E \vert \text{person i in seat j} \cap \text{person j not in seat i}) = P_{n-1},$$
> $$Pr(\text{person i in seat j} \cap \text{person j in seat i}) = \frac{1}{n(n-1)},$$
> $$Pr(\text{person i in seat j} \cap \text{person j not in seat i}) = \frac{n-2}{n(n-1)}.$$
> And this sums up as $$\frac1n P_{n-2} + \frac{n-2}{n}P_{n-1}.$$

I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Could somebody point me out? Or is my method completely wrong?

Comment: Why do you have $Pr(E\vert \text{person }i\text{ in seat }j  \cap \text{person }j\text{not in seat }i)=P_{n-1}$? I don't see this immediately; however $Pr(E\vert \text{person }i\text{ in seat }j  \cap \text{person }i\text{ not in seat }j)=P_{n-2}$ seems fine.

Comment: Note that if $!n$ is the amount of derangements (permutations of $n$ elements without any fixed points), one can use a similar strategy to the one you employed to prove that 
$$!n = (n-1)\cdot !(n-1) + (n-1)\cdot !(n-2)$$
for all $n\geq 2$.

Now using that your underlying probability space is equiprobable, can you deduce the recursive relation?

A proof for the combinatorial identity can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement.